# Why is there a blank line between my print and raw_input lines?

Tags: python

I've been searching like crazy and I haven't found out why my code prints an extra empty line inbetween my raw_input and print lines.

This is what it looks like:

```
print "--------------------------"
print "You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left."
print "Available Letters: "  + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed) + "."
letterGuessed = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
```

This is what I get as output:

```
--------------------------
You have 8 guesses left.
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz.

Please guess a letter:
```

And this what I want it to look like:

```
--------------------------
You have 8 guesses left.
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz.
Please guess a letter:
```

If someone could explain why this happens I'd really appreciate it!

here is the code for getAvailableLetters:

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    import string
    str = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char in lettersGuessed:
        if char in str:
            str = str.replace(char, "") 
    return str
```

full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd6314470a5696181c10

some functions aren't in use so please ignore them.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Forgot to add it. I had to copy the output by hand since I couldn't copy paste it from canopy terminal.

Comment: have you examined the string returned from `getAvailableLetters` to ensure it doesn't contain a newline?

Comment: @kdopen my getAvailableLetters function returns a simple string. I tried adding a return str + '.' at the end of it but still prints a blank line.

Comment: Try to use interpolation, is cleaner - http://repl.it/9H0 - and what possibly is creating another line, is the var getAvailbleLetters, as kdopen said. Nothing else creates a new line in your code.

Comment: paste your `getAvailableLetters` function code snippet please ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal I've edited my code to show it.

Comment: Actually, this may be a typo - but you store the answer in `letterGuessed` and pass `lettersGuessed` (note extra 's') into `getAvailableLetters`. We need to see more code. Does this happen only the first time you prompt the user, or every time?

Comment: Now your `getAvailableLetters` has been renamed to `getGuessedWord` and accepts two arguments.

Comment: You pasted different code again!  I think you should stop and download a fully copy of the code you're running and make sure you're running what you think you're running.

Comment: @Schwern This is my code. It's not something I've downloaded from anywhere.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 What I mean is you keep pasting code that does not match the output. Your current getAvailableLetters adds on its own `.`, and your print also adds a `.` so we should be seeing *two* dots in the output. I don't think you're running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @kdopen It's not a typo. I just thought printing the whole code wouldn't look well. But the code runs perfectly except for this one blanke line thing.

Comment: Unless you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this question should be closed. Try in some other IDE to crosscheck.

Comment: `str = string.ascii_lowercase` is hiding the built-in string data type. Who knows what that does :)

Comment: @kdopen O that might be the culprit! :) Thank you will look up if it does something weird for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** The conclusion from the discussion in the comments is it's a bug in Canopy IDE.

The code you're showing us is not the code you're running.

Your output is this:

```
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz.
```

Which is supposed to be printed by this (note the dot added on the end):

```
print "Available Letters: "  + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed) + "."
```

But `getAvailableLetters` also adds a dot on the end of its return value.

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    import string
    str = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char in lettersGuessed:
        if char in str:
            str = str.replace(char, "") 
    return str + '.'
```

So the output should be this:

```
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz..
```

My conclusion is the code you're showing us and the code you're running cannot be the same.  I would suggest pasting the code somewhere for us to examine fully.  [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) will do.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for helping me.

Here's the full code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd6314470a5696181c10

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Please please please verify that's the code you're running before going further. Then tell me what version of Python are you using? `python --version`.

Comment: So you don't get that weird linebreak inbetween raw_input and the print line?
I'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 I'm using Python 2.7.6 as well. No, I don't get a line break. I get your expected output.

Comment: Now that is weird. Is it something with canopy as and IDE?

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 That would be my next thought. Try running it in a regular terminal `python path/to/hangman.py` or whatever.

Comment: That works excellent! I don't know why Canopy is doing this... If you know of a better environment to learn python in please advice. Otherwise, really appreciate the help :)!

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 I'm not a Python programmer, and I'm generally of the opinion that handing beginners an IDE just adds more potential problems and layers to confuse, so take my recommendation with a grain of salt.  Consider [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) and using [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to edit.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I'm not a Canopy fan I think that the conclusion that its a Canopy bug is unfair.  I think its an issue when using raw_input involving the inclusion of IPython within an IDE.  Why?

My test code was:

```
print "Error if there is an extra line before 1"
print "Error if there is an extra line before 2"
guess = raw_input("This line should follow directly")
```

I tested the code in a number of environments (Python 2.7):

- Canopy: fail
- Spyder with IPython window: fail
- IPython in Jupyter QtConsole: fail

- ipython: good
- python:  good
- Spyder using a Python console.

So, I conclude that IPython, in a non-terminal environment is generating an extra linefeed for some reason before a raw_input().  Note that this still applies with Python 3.5 using input.

[image]