# How to remove the blank line above raw_input in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

I have in a while statement:

```
print 'Word', len(guessMe), 'letters long.'
print '------------- '
while verify != [] and guessesLeft > 0: 
  print 'You have', guessesLeft, 'guesses left.'
  userGuess = raw_input('Please guess a letter: ')
  userGuess = userGuess.lower()
  userGuessSingleton = list(userGuess)
  userGuessList = userGuessList + userGuessSingleton

  p = lettersList.index(userGuess) 
  del(lettersList[p]) 
  letters = "".join(lettersList) 
  print 'Available letters: ', letters
```

It outputs this:

```
Word is 10 letters long.
---------------
You have 13.0 guesses left.

Please guess a letter: a
```

Why is it that the other print statements don't create this issue? Does it have something to do with `raw_input()`? How do I remove that blank line after 'You have 13.0 guesses left'

**Note:** Nsh's [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093880/how-to-remove-the-blank-line-above-raw-input-in-python#comment46419262_29093880) doesn't work because it creates another problem: an indent of one space on the line after `"Please guess a letter: a"`

```
Please guess a letter: a
 Letters are 'abc'
```

Comment: what if you just combine the statement with the raw_input? Like raw_input('some statement\n please enter data: ')

Comment: Not getting, Can you post the output where you get blank line?

Comment: Print automatically adds newline character, to skip it you should call it with comma as suffix, e.g. `print 'some statement',`.

Comment: @AlanH I don't get the blank line. In what environment you get this?

Comment: @SAM You don't? I use Enthought Canopy. I can't fix it for the life of me.

Comment: Can you provide a complete program with the initializations also?

Comment: `raw_input()` does not, by itself, include an initial blank line. I cannot reproduce your output.

Comment: @Maxime verify is just another variable, it's a running list

Comment: The only possibility I see for you to obtain such an output is that you redefined `raw_input()` to print a newline before the prompt string.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your output

Comment: @AlanH Did you write the code in a different OS and then execute it in a different OS?

Comment: @BhargavRao No, I'm still getting the blank line. I have no idea why. It could be an issue with Canopy. It's not the first time it's happened. I ignored it in the past.

Comment: @AlanH you're using enthought? Then I guess I will add an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

In short, your code should not be doing what you claim it is doing. If this is all your code that could be affecting the output, then the new line before `raw_input` is unique to your situation only. I have tested your code with Ubuntu, OS X, and Windows 8 and this is the output I got:

```
Word 10 letters long.
------------- 
You have 13.0 guesses left.
Please guess a letter:
```

No new line. This might be a python bug.

Answer (score 1):

I check your code in python 2 ,3.there is no new line between print and raw_input. however you can use one ',' to combine two print in one line:

```
print "This",
print "is",
print "a test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and it is a problem with the Enthought Canopy editor. Also this is a duplicate of this question: [Why is there a blank line between my print and raw_input lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178047/why-is-there-a-blank-line-between-my-print-and-raw-input-lines)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have this same kind of output for the following code in Anaconda/Spyder Python 3.5 using input:

```
print("Welcome to the game, Hangman!")
print("I am thinking of a word that is " + str(len(secretWord)) + " letters long.")
print("-------------")
while guessesLeft > 0:
    print("You have " + str(guessesLeft) + " guesses left.")
    print("Available Letters: " + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
    guess = input("Please guess a letter: ")
    guessInLowerCase = guess.lower()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the game, Hangman!
I am thinking of a word that is 6 letters long.
-------------
You have 8 guesses left.
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Please guess a letter:
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using canpy as IDLE?
I think its bug with the IDLE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this line:

```
print("Available Letters: " + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
```

to

```
print("Available Letters: " + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed), end="")
```